Which position on an aircraft is generally safer?
Every time I flew, I thought about this. If I can choose, what seat (middle, window, or aisle) is generally safer in the (very rare) case of an accident? Also, what part of the aircraft (front, middle, or back) offers a higher chance of survival in case of a crash?
One question in particular that I've been wondering about for years is that are first-class seats (generally located at the front of the aircraft) safer? Or are they trading safety for comfort? As I personally do not have a preference (view or no view, freedom to move at will or not, it doesn't matter to me since I'm always sick and throwing up due to my motion sickness), I care and care only about safety.
Another question I've had is about the three-four-three configuration (on very long haul flights). Is the "four" in the middle safer than the two "threes" on the sides?
The situation I'm talking about is something like a forced emergency landing on land with terrain (but not on a steep slope/mountain), and the aircraft does not catch fire immediately. The nature of the crash should also be survivable, obviously. I'll appreciate any insights. Thanks.
(Side note: This may seem like a question that belongs to Aviation.SE, but since it's about passenger seating and safety, I think it might be better suited for this site.)

The seat in your car or taxi going to and from the airport is probably the most dangerous.

Why the downvotes? Any reasons?

@badjohn I agree, car fatalities are way much higher than aircraft fatalities. However, that's not relevant to my question.

On ships and planes, I find that motion sickness is minimised by having a view outside – a stable horizon.

@WeatherVane Unfortunately, that's not true on me. On airplanes, I throw up whatever the circumstances. On ships, I throw up if I do look outside, or if the ship wobbles and sways too much. On cars, looking outside helps a bit.

@LukeL Yes, that's why I used a comment rather than answer.  It just amuses / puzzles me that people worry about aircraft safety when the danger on the plane is tiny compared to road travel which few worry about.

It's possible that the nausea and fear go together. If you are obsessed with your safety, and imagine disasters, perhaps some therapy may help.

Why the large number of downvotes? Can anyone please tell me what's wrong with this question?

The consensus answer seems to be: a middle seat towards the back.
I guess anything that is going to kill you is going to be outside the plane, and typically towards the front, so you want to be as far away as possible.

Thanks for the great answer! So just as I thought, first-class passengers traded safety for comfort. But I guess it won't be true if the aircraft pitches up and falls on its tail. Or if there's a tail strike, although that's not what I asked for in the question. Still, thank you!

Tail strike won't usually affect inside of the plane.

In the Asiana crash (one of the very rare survivable accidents with any fatalities), the 3 fatalities were at the very back of the plane.

@LukeL: No, they trade money with comfort. The marginal decrease of safety is irrelevant (too small, compared other lifestyle decision we make). -- And personally I think we should reframe: I understand the safety concern, but nowadays flying is stressful (thanks few other passengers, and airlines procedures/cost cuts). Avoid middle seat. You may remove one microsecond of life expectancy (crash), but you add hours of it (less stress, and you enjoy quicker the post-flight).

@LukeL — it’s all statistical.  99 car crashes out of a 100, you are better off with your seat-belt buckled, but that 100th time, and you need to get out in a hurry...  Well, play the odds.

@AnishSheela — JAL 123 was brought down by tail-strike.  Of course, the strike occurred seven years before the crash.  Improper repairs eventually brought down the plane, killing most the passengers and crew; the incompetence and arrogance of the Japanese government killed all but four of the rest.

@GiacomoCatenazzi — actually, I crunched the numbers and if you are a healthy person in your 30s, changing your seat on one flight from the front to the back will extend your life (statistically) by almost 10 seconds. Of course, you’ll spend a lot more than that walking the additional distance to your seat...

@MichaelLorton Having a seat at the rear may not necessarily require a longer walk. In fact, my experience is that we usually board from the back, and our seating were usually at the middle-front, so we walked a lot. Thus, sometimes having a seat at the back of the aircraft have both the safety benefits and reduced walking!

@MichaelLorton: 10 seconds in much more then my estimates: I missed some factors. 10 seconds every flight is "a lot"
